# haskell - let/where equivalent within list comprehension?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

Is there a way to use `let`,`where` or otherwise define sub-expressions in a list comprehension so that it can be used both in the term and constraint?

From my experimenting, the following work:

```
[let x = i*i in x | i<-[1..10], i*i > 20]   --good
[i*i | i<-[1..10], let x=i*i in x > 20]     --good
```

But these do not bc of scope:

```
[let x = i*i in x | i<-[1..10], x > 20]  -- 'x' not in scope error
let x = i*i in [x | i<-[1..10], x > 20]  -- 'i' not in scope error
[x | i<-[1..10], x > 20] where x = i*i   --parse error on 'where'
```

So `let` works in one place or the other, but not both together!

The only way I've found to make it work (that is, avoid repeated expressions and possibly evaluations) is to add a silly singleton-list as I did here with `x<-[cat i [1..k]` as a constraint to the list comprehension:

```
> let cat x l = foldl1 (++) $ map show [x*i | i<-l]
maximum [x| i<-[1..9999], k<-[2..div 10 $ length $ show i], x<-[cat i [1..k]], sort x == "123456789"]
"932718654"
```

Or, contunuing the trivial example above,

```
[x | i<-[0..10], x<-[i*i], x > 20] --works
```

This seems a little silly, and is slightly lacking in clarity, tho it doesn't seem too inefficient.  Still, it would be nice if `let` or `where` worked across the whole comprehension. Can this be done?

Comment: Your second example, `[x | i<-[1..10], let x=i*i in x > 20]`, doesn't compile; did you mean `[i*i | i<-[1..10], let x=i*i in x > 20]`?

Comment: yep, thanks.  if the first worked i wouldve answered my own question

Comment: Euler project asks you, not to post solution to problems. I would kindly encourage you to replace the Euler example with something else.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You write it like this:

```
[x | i <- [0..10], let x = i*i, x > 20]
```

Notice there is no `in`. You can refer to `x` in both the term, and any constraints following the `let`. This form of `let` corresponds to the one in `do`-notation:

```
do i <- [0..10]
   let x = i*i
   guard (x > 20)
   return x
```

Here `x` is in scope from the `let` to the end of the `do`-block.

Comment: thanks, i knew there had to be something. i  would've been real disappointed if this were just some gaping hole in the language =P

Comment: @jon_darkstar, oh, don't be fooled.  There are numerous gaping holes in the language.  For example, the one that `Applicative` is supposed to fill.

Answer (score 5):

You almost had it; you can simply write `[x | i <- [0..10], let x = i*i, x > 20]` (note the `,` instead of `in`).  It's very similar to `do`-notation (in fact, you can use `do`-notation instead, and a recent GHC extension enables you to use list comprehensions for arbitrary monads).  If you're curious, you can find the syntax [in the Haskell 98 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions):

```
aexp -> [ exp | qual_1 , ... , qual_n ] (list comprehension, n >= 1)
qual -> pat <- exp                      (generator)
     |  let decls                       (local declaration)
     |  exp                             (guard)
```

As you can see, one of the valid qualifiers is `let decls`, which is exactly what you wanted.