# How to exclude a particular tuple from a list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Im very confused on how to filter out the element (1,1) from this list in the code below.

```
take 10 [ (i,j) | i <- [1,2], 
                  j <- [1..] ]
yields

[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10)]
```

My thoughts were to use something like filter but Im not too sure where to implement it.

My go was `Filter ((i,j) /=0) "the list"`

Thanks

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code. Include the actual code in your question. You can highlight it as a codeblock by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+k.

Comment: [`delete`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete) or `drop 1`

Comment: i <- [2,3..10] will start  the tuples with (1,2), exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt

```
Filter ((i,j) /=0) "the list"
```

has a few problems, which can be fixed.

First, the function is called `filter`. Second, its first argument must be a function: so you can use `\(i,j) -> ...` to take a list as input. Third, you want `(i,j) /= (1,1)` -- you can't compare a pair `(i,j)` to a single number `0`.

You should now be able to correct your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I understand better now, but where should the filter go.?.  Inside the list comprehension or is one of the arguments a list?

Comment: If you want to use `filter`, then it's `filter (predicate function) [ list comprehension ]`. Alternatively, you can probably modify your list comprehension to include the filtering condition, and avoid the explicit `filter`.

Comment: Alright thanks, and is the predicate function the rule where  (i,j) /= (1,1)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `filter`, you can also specify that you don't want `(1,1)` as an element within your list comprehension by adding a guard expression `(i,j) /= (1,1)`:

```
take 10 [ (i,j) | i <- [1,2], j <- [1..], (i,j) /= (1,1) ]
```

This is similar to how you might write a set comprehension (which list comprehensions mimic):

[image]

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067878) gives a nice example (`[x | i <- [0..10], let x = i*i, x > 20]`) of the three types of expression you can have in the tail end of a list comprehension:

- Generators, eg. `i <- [0..10]` provide the sources of values.
- Guards, eg. `x > 20` are arbitrary predicates - for any given values from the generators, the value will only be included in the result if all the predicates hold.
- Local declarations, eg. `let x = i*i` perform the same task as normal `let`/`where` statements.

<sup>Names for the different expressions taken from the [syntax reference](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html), expression `qual`.</sup>